# Getting the base class in a descriptor called via super()

Tags: python, inheritance, python-descriptors

I have a following (simplified of course) descriptor:

```py
class d:
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        print(instance, owner, self.method)
        return self.method(instance)
```

In `__get__()` I want to access the class where the decorated function is defined, but the `owner` argument is `B` on both invocations of `__get__()` that happen in the following code:

```py
class A:
    @d
    def f(self):
        return "A"

class B(A):
    @d
    def f(self):
        return super().f + "B"

print(B().f)
```

I've checked [the Descriptor HowTo Guide section](https://docs.python.org/3.11/howto/descriptor.html#invocation-from-super) on calling descriptors via `super()` and it says that this invocation indeed passes the subclass type to the parent class `__get__()`. Does it suggest I may need to define `__getattribute__()` to get what I want, or is there a different way? I understand that the `super()` call doesn't just return `A` but a proxy for `B` but I feel like there should be a way to get `A` in the descriptor.

I'll also appreciate a clearer explanation of what is happening in my code.

Comment: With `print(owner.__mro__, instance ...)` we see (B, A, object). But I guess that's not enough for the hidden use case that underlies this question?

Comment: This isn't information the descriptor has available (short of parsing fully qualified function names). Why does the descriptor need to know about `A`?

Comment: @J_H @chepner yeah, `__mro__` is not useful here I think, because per the real world use case `B.f()` is user-provided and calls `super().f` assuming it will call `A.f`. At the same time, `d.__get__()` I'm writing wants to access some attributes of the class object, so that calling `B.f` would use data related to `B` and calling either `A.f` or `super().f` would use data related to `A`.

Comment: The context is https://github.com/scrapinghub/web-poet/pull/151 , though the super() use case is not described there.

Comment: It sounds like you want access to more stuff, which isn't being {explicitly, implicitly} passed in. So require that A / B make more stuff available to you, even if it costs the app having to specify additional args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier thing to do is to record, in the descriptor, the class where it is defined at class creation time.

Since Python 3.6 that is possible due to the addition of the `__set_name__` method to the descriptor protocol.

The `owner` parameter received in `__set_name__` is the actuall class where the descriptor is defined. It can then be set as a descriptor attribute:

```
class d:
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name  # should be the same as self.method.__name__
        self.owner = owner

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        print(f"{instance=}, {owner=}, {self.owner=}, {self.method=}")
        return self.method(instance)
```

And running this along with your example `A` and `B`:

```
(env311) [gwidion@fedora tmp01]$ python script.py 
instance=<__main__.B object at 0x7f78c6094110>, owner=<class '__main__.B'>, self.owner=<class '__main__.B'>, self.method=<function B.f at 0x7f78c607d800>
instance=<__main__.B object at 0x7f78c6094110>, owner=<class '__main__.B'>, self.owner=<class '__main__.A'>, self.method=<function A.f at 0x7f78c607d760>
AB
```

Without the resort to `__set_name__` the thing to do would be indeed to walk linearly through the `__mro__` until it would find `self`, as long as it had not been shadowed by another decorator of the same kind:

```
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        for cls in owner.__mro__:
            if self in cls.__dict__.values():
                defined_at = cls 
            break
        else:
            raise RuntimeError()
        print(f"{instance=}, {owner=}, {self.defined_at=}, {self.method=}")
        return self.method(instance)
```